# Restart docker containers without restarting reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, docker, arch-linux

My containers can't restart properly if I don't take down the reverse proxy (nginx) before. These logs show the sequence of events:

```
2017-03-23 19:50:29 140019590191872 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mar 23 19:50:57 server env[4805]: example_peerjs_1 exited with code 137
mar 23 19:50:49 server env[4805]: example_mariadb_1 exited with code 0
mar 23 19:50:48 server env[4805]: example_es_1 exited with code 143
mar 23 19:50:48 server env[4805]: example_web_1 exited with code 0
mar 23 19:50:57 server env[5951]: Removing example_web_1 ...
mar 23 19:50:57 server env[5951]: Removing example_mariadb_1 ...
mar 23 19:50:57 server env[5951]: Removing example_es_1 ...
mar 23 19:51:56 server systemd[1]: example.service: Stopping timed out. Terminating
mar 23 19:51:56 server systemd[1]: Stopped example Service.
mar 23 19:51:56 server systemd[1]: example.service: Unit entered failed state
mar 23 19:51:56 server systemd[1]: example.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.

-- "systemctl restart example"

mar 23 19:51:56 server systemd[1]: Started example Service.
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: Starting example_web_1
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: Starting example_peerjs_1
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: Starting example_mariadb_1
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: Starting example_es_1
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: b'Container is marked for removal and cannot be started.'
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: ERROR: for peerjs  Cannot start service peerjs: b'Container is marked for removal and cannot be started.'
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: ERROR: for es  Cannot start service es: b'Container is marked for removal and cannot be started.'
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: ERROR: for mariadb  Cannot start service mariadb: b'Container is marked for removal and cannot be started.'
mar 23 19:52:18 server env[7372]: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
mar 23 19:52:18 server systemd[1]: example.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mar 23 19:52:19 server env[7714]: Removing example_peerjs_1 ...
mar 23 19:52:19 server env[7714]: Removing example_web_1 ...
mar 23 19:52:19 server env[7714]: Removing example_mariadb_1 ...
mar 23 19:52:19 server env[7714]: Removing example_es_1 ...
mar 23 19:53:19 server env[7714]: ERROR: for example_mariadb_1  b'Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem dfbe00a23038e5427c340afc41b43827042e9ec75afb2b4620462639b01e5f5e: Device is Busy'
mar 23 19:53:19 server env[7714]: ERROR: for example_es_1  b'Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem 3c4f49634c5f602dbb752e12d4d1d26dbb1f98cbf9b0d425313f513ee52bb717: Device is Busy'
mar 23 19:53:19 server env[7714]: ERROR: for example_peerjs_1  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
mar 23 19:53:19 server env[7714]: ERROR: for example_web_1  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
mar 23 19:53:19 server env[7714]: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
mar 23 19:53:19 server env[7714]: If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
mar 23 19:53:19 server systemd[1]: example.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
mar 23 19:53:19 server systemd[1]: example.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

After all of this I have to restart the docker daemon to get back to an usable state. This means a lot of downtime.

This particular project uses this docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

    web:
        image: example
        volumes:
            - web:/var/www/html/storage
        ports:
            - ${LOCAL_PORT}:80

    es:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2
        environment:
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
            - xpack.security.enabled=false
        volumes:
            - es:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

    peerjs:
        image: example-peerjs

volumes:
    es:
        driver: local
    web:
        driver: local
    mariadb:
        driver: local
```

This is the nginx configuration for this project:

```
upstream example_backend {
  server localhost:82;
  keepalive 32;
}
server {
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
  location ^~ {
    proxy_pass  http://example_backend;
    proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header host $http_host;
  }
  charset utf-8;
  include h5bp/basic.conf;
}
```

Systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=example Service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/http/example
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env docker-compose -p "example" -f "docker-compose.yml" up
ExecStop=/usr/bin/env docker-compose -p "example" -f "docker-compose.yml" down

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

Dockerfile for "example":

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng12-dev cron \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && a2enmod headers

ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/example
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/example

ADD . /var/www
ADD docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

ADD . /var/www
ADD docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

VOLUME /var/www/html/storage
```

"docker info":

```
Containers: 14
 Running: 11
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 66
Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:0-33097-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 8.75 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 23.83 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 13.27 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.134 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.137 (2016-11-30)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 977c511eda0925a723debdc94d09459af49d082a
runc version: a01dafd48bc1c7cc12bdb01206f9fea7dd6feb70
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.8.6-x86_64-linode78
Operating System: Arch Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.856 GiB
Name: server
ID: ACCU:HOO7:WIMC:R7WM:MBWC:6F2F:G4G3:DH3X:A7L4:DLDC:KDOL:TPAA
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Is there any way to avoid this problem?
Linux, docker and nginx versions:

```
Linux server 4.8.6-x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 14:51:21 EDT 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
docker 1:17.03.0-1
nginx 1.10.3-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. For anyone with this problem: stop using devicemapper in loop mode. I switched to overlay2, since I'm on the latest kernel.